# I can't play video saved in Directory path and AVPlayer in swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2

I'm recording a video with `AVFoundation`, and I created a preview from the video, when I finish to record a video, the video is playing in the preview, but when I save the video using:

```
var fileName = "\(self.tField.text!).mp4"
fileName = fileName.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "_")

let path = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
//let originVideoFile = self.filePath
let destinationVideoFile = path.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.filePath)

//try data!.writeToURL(destinationVideoFile!, options: [])
let fileManager = NSFileManager()
fileManager.createFileAtPath((destinationVideoFile?.path)!, contents: data, attributes: nil)
```

The video file is created but I don't have access to this file when I want re play the video, but the camera roll can play the video.

[image: This is the preview of video]

[image: and this is the problem when I try to re play the video]

to get the "`filePath`" I'm using the delegate method of `AVFoundation`:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {

    print("capture did finish")
    print(captureOutput);
    print(outputFileURL);
    self.filePath = outputFileURL
    performSegueWithIdentifier("previewVideo", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "previewVideo"{
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! PreviewVC
        destination.filePath = self.filePath
        destination.videoDelegate = self.videoDelegate
    }
}
```

and pass the data with "`prepareForSegue`"

I return a video object with the information needed, and when I want to re play a video, I using the method "`didSelect`" of the collectionview I create a "`AVPlayer`" and use the name of the file to found the path of the video, then the file exist but can't play

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    videoSingleObject = videoObjects[indexPath.item]
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let filePath = url.URLByAppendingPathComponent(videoSingleObject.nameOfFile)!.path!
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(filePath) {
        print("FILE AVAILABLE")
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(filePath, nil, nil, nil)
        print("PATH: \(filePath)")
        let videoPath = NSURL(string: filePath)!
        //filePathURL = videoPath
        print(videoPath)
        asset = AVAsset(URL: videoPath)
        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        print("DURATION: \(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration))")
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        player.play()
        }else {
        print("THE DIRECTORY NOT EXIST")
    }
}
```

but I use "`UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(filePath, nil, nil, nil)`" to share the video in the cameraRoll, and in the cameraRoll the video is can play.

Comment: Great working code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found the error, the problem is the URL reference, i'm using a NSURL(string: filePath), i solved the problem using NSURL(fileURLwithPath: filePath)